# mysql insert query with mix of static value and inner select query

Tags: mysql

I have a table called **productcategory** I want to insert two static values to the columns **category_name** and **parent_id** and need to insert column **sort_order** with a value generated from inner select query

```
INSERT INTO productcategory(category_name,parent_id,sort_order) 
values('Flowers',0,(select MAX(sort_order)+1 from productcategory where parent_id=0))
```

SQL query not working
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is the actual error message classified? I cannot think of any other reason for not sharing it with us. My guess is that you cannot select from the table in a subquery which you try to modify.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select from same table as an Insert or Update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205190/select-from-same-table-as-an-insert-or-update)

Answer (score 1):

You can't select from the table in a sub query which you try to update or insert.

As per my knowledge this can be achieved by using `SET` method like below.

```
SELECT @maxSortOrder := IFNULL(MAX(sort_order),0)+1 FROM productcategory WHERE parent_id=0;
INSERT INTO productcategory(category_name,parent_id,sort_order) VALUES('Flowers',0,@maxSortOrder);
```

This may help you.

Answer (score 1):

It should work like this:

```
INSERT INTO productcategory(category_name,parent_id,sort_order)
SELECT 'Flowers', 0, MAX(sort_order)+1
FROM   productcategory
WHERE  parent_id = 0
```

Comment: Glad it works, so please accept the answer so others can see this question is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Now try this:

```
CREATE TABLE dupproduct AS (SELECT * FROM productcategory);

INSERT INTO productcategory (
  category_name,
  parent_id,
  sort_order
) 
VALUES
  (
    'Flowers',
    0,
    (SELECT 
      MAX(sort_order) + 1 
    FROM
      dupproduct 
    WHERE parent_id = 0)
  );


  DROP TABLE dupproduct;
```

Comment: Do you seriously suggest to copy the entire table to make the query work?