# ERROR 1093 (HY000): Nested select on insert

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an issue whereby a query that works perfectly fine in Postgres fails in MySQL. I have checked out other stack questions and googled the error but still cannot quite figure out what is wrong.

```
insert into queue (name, id) values ('name',(select max(id)+1 from queue));
```

Now it just fails with the following error

```
ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'queue' for update in FROM clause
```

Comment: It would seem SOoooo much simpler to make the `id` column a `Auto Increment` column and then this would happen automatically and be guaranteed to be right

Comment: @Jens it is actually a valid name - I've corrected the statement to reflect real name

Comment: @RiggsFolly indeed - but have to work with what I have at the moment

Comment: That duplicate posting is rather abstruse.  I'd sure like to see the simple answer to this question exactly as posted.  And to me, certainly the top answer isn't all that helpful.  I can see the second answer `INSERT INTO tableA SET fieldA = (SELECT max(x.fieldA) FROM tableA x)+1;` is close, but not exactly what is asked here.

Comment: @zipzit - indeed...

Comment: @MaciejCygan if it were me... I'd use the hints from [the reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205190/select-from-same-table-as-an-insert-or-update), figure out a workable solution, rewrite this question again, and submit your own answer immediately.  Then delete the original.  There is no good way to downvote a "This question already has an answer..." submit that I can see.  This is not a duplicate.. very similar, yes, but not a duplicate.